# Cannot set user.is_active to false

Tags: django

I have a custom user model and I am trying to deactive the user but it is not saving. There are also no error messages.

My model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from model_utils import FieldTracker

class User(AbstractUser):
    # ... just some additional attributes

   objects = UserManager()
   tracker = FieldTracker()


u = User.objects.get(email="some@email.de")
u.is_active = False
u.save()
u.refresh_from_db()
u.is_active # Still returns True but should be False
```

**Solution**
I found the reason why the save did not work is the Fieldtracker. Unfortunately, it is not mentioned in their documentation. The FieldTracker cannot handle the the attribute is_active=True of the base class. Workaround is to use FieldTracker to track specific fields (except is_active):

```
email_tracker = FieldTracker(fields=['email'])
```

Comment: And you have nothing added in User save method or no signals are triggered on post_save or pre_save which could change is_active back to True?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Were the first things I double checked.

Comment: That's weird, what version of Django and Python?

Comment: Django: 2.2.16, Python: 3.9.6.

Comment: @TrueGopnik Problem is realted to change detection via FieldTracker

Comment: Nice to hear that you solved problem, so FieldTracker can't handle any boolean field or just is_active?

Comment: @TrueGopnik is_active is set as an attribute in the base class AbstractBaseUser  (is_active=True) and will overriden with a boolen field in the class AbstractUser (inherits from AbstractBaseUser) . Seems that FieldTracker cannot handle this specific combination. Usually, it can track all field types.

Comment: The underlying issue was in Django itself, and was [fixed in Django 4.0](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30427?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2).